# Why do the math problems in my program repeat the same equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to make a math problem in Python, since I'm a beginner learning how to code. Basically, it asks you how many questions you want to answer, and to answer questions of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division correctly.

Let me show you the code I have, so far.

```
import random

num_question = (int)(input("Enter how many questions would you like to solve: "))
num1 = random.randint (0,20)
num2 = random.randint (0,20)
oper = ["+","-","*","/"]
operator = random.choice(oper) #chooses a variable in the "oper" list at random. Then it is used in the question

for count in range (0, num_question):
    question = (num1, operator, num2) #e.g. What is 6 - 2
    print (question)
    guess = (int)(input("Enter here: "))
    answer = 0
    if operator == "+": #if the operator chooses addition, the answer will equal the sum of both numbers. The same goes for the other if statements.
        answer = (num1 + num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        answer = (num1 - num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        answer = (num1 * num2)
    elif operator == "/":
        answer = (num1 / num2)
    
    if guess == answer: #if the answer is equal to the question, then it's correct and proceeds. Otherwise, it doesn't.
        print ("Correct!")
        continue
    else:
        print ("Incorrect. Please try again.")
```

However, the drawback is that the same question repeats everytime (I am using my old laptop, so the p button and the quotation button is broken). Now my question is how to make the questions not repeat themselves.

Comment: This isn't C, you don't write `(int)` to cast. It happens to work because it's the same as calling the `int()` function, but it looks like you're thinking in C.

Comment: `question` is a string like "What is 2+2?" - that's certainly not going to be equal to `answer`.  In fact you overwrote the user's entered `answer` with the correct answer, so there's no longer anything to compare.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "(int) to cast". Could you please specify?

Comment: I mean `(int)(input("Enter here: "))`. It's normally written as `int(input("Enter here: "))`

Comment: @jasonharper So what you're saying is that I should remove the strings in (question). Do I have that right?

Comment: Why do you think `question` should equal `answer`? Do you know what their values are? Try printing them out in the `else` clause to see why it fails.

Comment: Alright, so here's what I need to do: add a new variable and keep the answer separate from the guess, and assign the variables rather than compare them. As well as some other things. Got it. I'll report back when I get the results. Older sibling is on the PC at the moment.

Comment: It worked! But now the questions repeat for the entire for loop. Now for me to solve that issue. I think it might require a while loop.

Comment: You have to randomize `num1`, `num2`, and `operator` in the for-block before you ask for an answer.

Comment: @ack I see what you mean, but how would I go about doing that? I apologize for my lack of information. I'm a beginner in coding.

Comment: Copy 3 lines: `num1 = random.randint (0,20)` `num2 = random.randint (0,20)` and `operator = random.choice(oper)` directly below `print ("Correct!")` in order to get new numbers and a new operator for each question after the question has been answered correctly.

Comment: The edits were definitely necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems.

1. You are testing for equality with "==" inside the "if" statements, when you probably would like to assign the true answer to a variable to compare to the user's guess
2. You are comparing the answer to the question, which is a string, which will never be equal

Fix the first one by creating a new variable for the true answer to keep it separate from the guess. Fix the second by comparing the guess to the real answer.

```
    guess = (int)(input("Enter here: "))
    answer = 0
    if operator == "+": #if the operator chooses addition, the answer will equal the sum of both numbers. The same goes for the other if statements.
        answer = (num1 + num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        answer = (num1 - num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        answer = (num1 * num2)
    elif operator == "/":
        answer = (num1 / num2)
    
    if answer == guess : #if the answer is equal to the question, then it's correct and proceeds. Otherwise, it doesn't.
        print ("Correct!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer == (num1 + num2)
```

You're using two equal signs, which is an equality *test*, not an *assignment*.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the user's answer with the correct result. Then you're comparing that with the question text, not the user's answer.

Also you need to use `=` to assign, not `==`.

Use a different variable for the correct answer, and compare that with the user's answer.

```
or count in range (0, num_question):
    question = ("What is " + str(num1) + " " + operator + " " + str(num2) + "?") #e.g. What is 6 - 2
    print (question)
    answer = int(input("Enter here: "))
    if operator == "+": #if the operator chooses addition, the answer will equal the sum of both numbers. The same goes for the other if statements.
        correct = (num1 + num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        correct = (num1 - num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        correct = (num1 * num2)
    elif operator == "/":
        correct = (num1 / num2)
    
    if correct == answer: 
        print ("Correct!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect. Please try again.")
```